# Run script from PNPM bin with env-file

Tags: node.js, pnpm

I have an `.env` file:

```ini
STH=1
```

In Node 20 I can do:

```
node --env-file=.env -e "console.log(process.env.STH)"
1
```

Is there a way, I can incorporate this into running a script with "PNPM". For illustration (I do not want actually to run prettier) with Prettier in the package.json:

```
pnpm prettier

Usage: prettier [options] [file/dir/glob ...]
```

Is there a way I can pre-process a `.env` file by using the new NodeJs `--env-file` feature and use the result with a pnpm script?  In the "Prettier" example the prettier script would have access to all env variables defined in `.env`. `--env-file` is not allowed in `NODE_OPTIONS`.